# PHP exporting several excel files

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to export several tables from a database and creating a excel file for each table using PHP. The loop however is "bugged". Instead of creating a new file for each loop it just puts all data into the same file.

The code:

```php
  foreach ($pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;") as $allTables) {
    $table = $allTables[0];

    $allDataStmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table;");
    $allDataStmt->execute();

    $fieldcount = $allDataStmt->columnCount();

    $col_title = "";
    $data = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fieldcount; $i++) {
      $col = $allDataStmt->getColumnMeta($i);
      $column = $col['name'];
      $col_title .= '<Cell ss:StyleID="2"><Data ss:Type="String">' . $column . '</Data></Cell>';
    }

    $col_title = '<Row>' . $col_title . '</Row>';

    while ($row = $allDataStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
      $line = '';
      foreach ($row as $value) {
        if ((!isset($value)) or ($value == "")) {
          $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>\t';
        } else {
          $value = str_replace('"', '', $value);
          $value = '<Cell ss:StyleID="1"><Data ss:Type="String">' . $value . '</Data></Cell>\t';
        }
        $line .= $value;
      }
      $data .= trim("<Row>" . $line . "</Row>") . "\n";
    }

    $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);

    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $table . ".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
  }
}
```

If I kill the loop after the first iteration it exports the data correctly from ONE table. If I let the loop run it just loads the same file with the data and the file becomes corrupted. I can't even open it in Excel.

What am I missing? Been stuck with this for hours.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it by chance that your `$table` variable keeps accessing the first index of the array, in `$allTables[0]`? Perhaps you need an counter/index variable so it doesn't keep referencing the same instance?

Comment: @MaxVoisard I thought about that too, but when I print out the tables and only the tables they are printed out correctly. They don't appear more than once. I hope I didn't misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: After some research, I've discovered that what you are attempting is not possible for a single HTTP request, and the best solution is to add to a .zip file. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting with making multiple different attachments in the same HTTP request is not possible. The HTTP protocol does not have support for downloading multiple files. The most common workaround is to put the files in a zip archive for the client to download, so something like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = "excel_tables.zip";

if ($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
    foreach ($pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;") as $allTables) {
        // (Your logic to build Excel file)

        $file_content = $col_title . "\n" . $data;

        $file_name = $table . ".xls";
        file_put_contents($file_name, $file_content);

        // Add file to the zip file
        $zip->addFile($file_name);
    }

    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zip_name);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_name));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile(__DIR__ . "/" . $zip_name);
}
```

Comment: wow even better. Thank you! This was actually what I was planning to do after fixing this issue haha. I tried this now but I keep getting this error: Warning: ZipArchive::addFile(): No such file or directory in xxxxx

Comment: See my edit - it looks like the server root path should be included for the zip file's location. I also edited the `open()` method to be wrapped in a conditional that overwrites that same zip file instead of creating it. Not sure, but hopefully it works.

Comment: unfortunately I keep getting the same error. If I use that condition you added nothing happens at all. If I don't use it I get the same error as earlier.

Comment: Did you change the `$zip_name` variable to include the server root?

Comment: yes I did.   $zip_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/excel_tabels.zip";

Comment: I realize the problem wasn't with the server path of the zip file, but rather the attempt to add a file that doesn't exist. Did you ever add the contents you generated to an Excel file, like through the variables `$col_title` and `$data`, and then post it to the server? I don't see that in your code. I've edited my answer in case that is what's missing.

Comment: max you are a godsend it's working now. the files are being written into a zip file. Thank you so much! Is it somehow possible to get the zip file downloaded as a user? I mean if someone clicks download it will get saved to his/hers pc?

Comment: You're welcome and good to hear it's working - as for your question, do you mean for the zip file to simply download on a button click? If so, then yes, you just have to call this code upon a form submission.

Comment: yes exactly. Well it's not working. The files are being downloaded to the folder specified in the code. But it doesn't get downloaded to my "downloads" folder on my PC.

Comment: There may be a few missing headers necessary to download the zip to the client's PC. Check the updated answer.

Comment: still not working. It's weird because I used the exact same headers earlier and it did start downloading when I was doing the individual files. It's weird how it isn't downloading now with the same headers haha.

Comment: From what it looks like in the docs I just read, wherever the zip file is being uploaded on the server, you must include that path before the readfile() method. See my edit - if "__DIR__" doesn't work, just use the current working directory where the code resides.

Comment: still not working unfortunately. I'll look further into it tomorrow. It's 5 am here as of now and I've been doing this for 10+ hours. I really appreciate your help and you taking your time! You've gotten me a long way. Thanks alot again!

Comment: I solved it. I was printing out something in the foreach-loop and that was causing it not to download. Everything working fine now!

Comment: Okay, good to hear it downloads.